# How to get my WiFi notifications back into English?

Tags: wi-fi, notifications, languages, localization

For some reason my WiFi notifications have started appearing in *I think* Polish, or something with a similar alphabet, I don't even have any such languages installed as far as I can see.

This problem has survived through an update to 4.3 Jelly Bean.  Phone is Galaxy Note 2, (GT-N7100), on O2 UK.

The 3 messages that I get when turning WiFi on and off with my **home** network - which has an English name, are in the attached picture.

[image: Messages on disconnecting and connecting WiFi]
<sup>Messages on disconnecting and connecting WiFi (click for larger image)</sup>

Google Translate tells me that they are Polish for "Available connectivity package", "No access to Network" & "Available Wi-Fi connectivity".

Comment: Polish uses the Latin alphabet like English, with a small number of extra letters, so if you're seeing a different alphabet, it's not Polish. Could you show us exactly what these notifications look like?

Comment: As @DanHulme indicated: A screenshot might be helpful. Further, what notifications are we talking about? Maybe you're just referring to the SSID of a certain network, which indeed *might* have a funny name?

Comment: Dostepna with a squiggle under one or more fo the letters seems to be the most common word when I connect to my *home* network.

Comment: @Izzy - I have added screen shots and translations.

Comment: Thanks! Just resized it to fit better :) And yes, that definitly looks like Polish – and it's not just the SSID. Could it be you've installed some app when that started happening?

Comment: I didn't notice it in conjunction with installing one particular app - but updates are happening just about every day...